# when will this recursion terminate

Tags: c++, recursion

I am not familiar with recursion. the following piece of code is a simplification of a long piece of code, which really works. There is no `"return"` anywhere in it. Could anybody tell me the logic here regarding when it will terminate?

```
void query(const Node& node) {
    if(node.isLeaf()) {if(node.value > 10) result.push(node);}
    else {
        for(unsigned i=0; i<node.numChild; ++i) {
            query(node.children[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not correct C++ syntax. However in C++ `void` function doesn't need `return` statement. This recursion seems to terminate on leaves.

Comment: This is not a complete function so it's hard to reason about it but as far as I can see, it only recurses for non-leaf nodes. Unless you have cycles in your graph, it will eventually stop.

Comment: this is a tree @5gon12eder

Comment: Please take the hard way and step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: _"There is no "return" ..."_ you don't need to _return_ explicitly, but you need to specify a _return type_, at least `void`.

Comment: thank u i just added one.

Comment: @daydayup Post more realistic _code_, at best your ***real** one.

Comment: My preferred way of writing this code would have been `if(node.isLeaf() && node.value > 10) { result.push(node); }
for(unsigned i=0; i<node.numChild; ++i) { query(node.children[i]); }` with slightly less `if`s and no `else`.

Comment: @CompuChip why no else here? my understanding is that without else, even when node.isLeaf()==true, it will still attempt to go through the for() loop, which is unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

One would suspect, it terminates on this path

```
if(node.isLeaf()) {do something;}
```

since *leafs* in a tree are considered not to have any further child nodes.

But that totally depends on what `do something;` involves. If there's an indirect recursion to `query()` it may never stop recursion anyways.

As for your comments, explicit `return` statements aren't needed with `void` function return types.

Comment: sorry i forgot to give more info on "do something". "do something" doesn't involve query(), i just gave an example to it